# How do I get the mimetype and file ID using the Microsoft Graph API for OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are integrating our product with MS OneDrive. Our users will connect their MS accounts and choose a folder that they want us to pull files from.  Our system only supports certain file types so we have to get the mimetype information AND the file ID after making a request. But we can't find a request that brings back both pieces of information so we can determine if we should pull a file or not.

This is close, but it doesn't give us the mimetype information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_recent?view=odsp-graph-online

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method lets you retrieve all kinds of information about a file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online

It returns a `driveItem` object, that has a `file` property. And that `file` property has a `mimeType` property. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/file?view=odsp-graph-online.

Unfortunately that means, that you will need more than one request to get the information you want.

If filtering by filename suffix is good enough for you, you can query OneDrive like this:

```
POST /search/query
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "driveItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "filetype:docx OR filetype:doc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries

Comment: So our process would look something like this:

Comment: So our process needs to look something like this:  1) Poll the folder to see if there are any new files; 2) If there are new files then make a driveItem request to get the IDs; 3) Then we need to request the properties of the items to get the mimetype to determine if it is a file we support; 4) For any new file of the mimetype we support, we then pull those files over;  Is that correct?  That is a lot more complicated than what Google provides for their Google Drive integrations.  Thank you so much for your help.  I'm a PM so any specific code recommendations for my developer is appreciated!

Comment: Step 2) is not needed. Step 1) (something like `GET /me/drive/recent`) gives you the  `id`s. But I think I found an alternative solution. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Let me run this by our engineering team. I really appreciate this and will get back to you!!

Comment: Hi there. Our engineering team really wants to use mimetype instead of file type. Apparently there are edge cases where file type could create issues where mimetype would not run into that problem.  I should probably get more details.  I'll look around and try to find some samples out there for connecting to OneDrive and needing mimetype.